# Problem with 1.33 GB hard drive and Disk Utility on Macbook Air 11 2015 a1465

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, memory

I have a Macbook Air 11 2015 a1465 (Apple A1465 MacBook Air 11 "(Early 2015) (i5-5250U | 4GB | 128SSD)).

Deleted the hard drive via Disk Utility.
In the process, some unplanned process took place.
Now there is such a big problem ...

Hard drive 128 GB.
But after I removed the hard drive, it became 1.33 GB.
And the system hid the remaining 126.67 GB.

Disk Utility now does not give access to the hard drive, and does nothing at all with these 126.67 GB of frozen space.

Disk0 shows an Apple disk image.
The terminal shows 13 partitions on the disk (maybe this is normal).

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

diskutil list
diskutil cs list[image]

Comment: What kind of "some unplanned process took place"? How did you delete the drive, from where?

Comment: Try booting from an external drive

Comment: I was trying to clear the entire hard drive for a system update and uninstalled the Macintosh HD

Comment: Please *edit* your question with additional information, don‘t post it as answers.

Comment: Can you share the output of `diskutil apfs list` and `sw_vers`?